# Extend dict from key/values pair to key/value pair in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
myDict = {'121': ['adrian', 'alex', 'peter'], '122': ['john', 'vic', 'bill']}
```

I want to 'extend' my dictionary so that each key/value pair consists of one value, instead of a list. Tried iterating with myDict.keys() and myDict.values() and construct a new dict, didnt work out (i'm quite new to python3). This is what I want to achieve:

```
myNewDict = {'121': 'adrian', '121': 'alex', '121': 'peter', '122': 'john', '122': 'vic', '122':'bill'}
```

Comment: This is not possible as there cannot be multiple entries for the same key. You will overwrite the value over and over again. Just check what your posted code does.

Comment: look at map operations

Comment: As @Nras said you can't have multiple entries for one key. What are you trying to do once you have your (hypothetical) dictionary?

Comment: As it stands, you're really asking how to build a tuple out of a dictionary.

Comment: I see. Wat I eventually was trying to achieve is to do a swap of unique values. So each 'unique name' would get one or more 'numbers' as their value.

`myNewDict = {'adrian': '121', 'alex': '121'}`

if for example adrian will pop up again in myDict with number 130 or so. Then:

`myNewDict = {'adrian': ['121', 130'], 'alex': '121'}`

Comment: As others have posted - that's not even possible. The more important question is what do you *really* want to achieve? Are you just trying to iterate over the values per key?

Comment: The way to do "one or more 'numbers' as their value" is to store a data structure that holds "one or more 'numbers" - a list. Use `myNewDict = {'adrian': ['121']}` even when you have only one value. Do you really want to be checking the type of your value to figure out whether you have multiple values or not?

Comment: Yes, you could see the names as staff members and I want to store their staff ids in the list, in such a way that I wont have any duplicate staff member names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments above, here's how to invert the dict and allow multiple values for each key:

```
from collections import defaultdict
myNewDict = defaultdict(list)
for staff_id, names in myDict.items():
    for name in names:
        myNewDict[name].append(staff_id)
```

You might use a `defaultdict` of `set` and `add` instead of `list` and `append` if order doesn't matter:

```
from collections import defaultdict
myNewDict = defaultdict(set)
for staff_id, names in myDict.items():
    for name in names:
        myNewDict[name].add(staff_id)
```

Comment: Throws an error:    
`myNewDict[name].add(staff_id)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! got it now with datastructure set() since it lists only unique values.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about collisions being clobbered, here's a 1-line solution (plus import):

```
import functools                                                                   
myDict = {'121': ['adrian', 'alex', 'peter'], '122': ['john', 'vic', 'bill']}   

print(functools.reduce( lambda x,y: dict(x, **y), (dict(map(lambda x: (x,i), myDict[i])) for i in myDict)))
```

---

To break apart what this is doing:

```
# This is a generator that creates a new dictionary out of each key/valuelist

(dict(map(lambda val: (val,key), myDict[key])) for key in myDict)

# => {'adrian': '121', 'alex': '121': 'peter': '121'}
# => {'john': '122', 'bill': '122', 'vic': '122'}
```

---

Once you have that,then call

```
functools.reduce( lambda x,y: dict(x, **y), <generator here>)
```

[Reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) takes a function and applies it

> cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.

`dict(mydict, **yourdict)` combines dictionaries by way of [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Which means that this takes the first dictionary from the list, and combines it with the next dictionary in the list, and so-on and so-forth until all the dictionaries in the list have been combined into one grand dictionary.

---

All that being said, I'd probably do something like this instead:

```
inverted = dict((name, k) for k, v in myDict.items() for name in v)
```

Alternate syntax using a dictionary comprehension:

```
inverted = {name: k for k, v in myDict.items() for name in v}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, these preserve only one value if a name appears more than once. The OP clarifies in comments that collisions need to be maintained: " if for example adrian will pop up again in myDict with number 130 or so. Then:  `myNewDict = {'adrian': ['121', 130'], 'alex': '121'}`"

Comment: indeed @PeterDeGlopper, that is what I want

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want, @klabanus? Or do you want `{'adrian': ['121', '130'], 'alex': ['121']}`? Because those are pretty fundamentally different, in terms of what you can do with them.

Comment: Good point @WayneWerner, eventually the id's need to be in a list, even if it's only one value.